# Flow Settings in Cura 2.4 for Ultimaker 2+ not available (suspected overextrusion filling small holes)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, extrusion, ultimaker-2

Cura 2.4 reports that the (printer-dependant) G-Code mode prevents the "Flow" (extrusion rate adjustment percentage) setting from being available. Why? I am using an Ultimaker 2+. Is a firmware update required?

I know the "Flow" can by dynamically adjusted on the 3D printer (either in materials or while printing).

I am asking because I have small holes (1 mm) that seem to slice fine but get filled so the extrusion probably is not that optimally tuned. I suspected reducing the material rate would improve this but changing it on the printer (97%) did not yield noticable results and below that it looked worse.

Comment: The Ultimaker / Marlin firmware documentation at https://github.com/Ultimaker/Ultimaker2Marlin states "M221 S- set extrude factor override percentage".

Answer (score 2):

For the Ultimaker 2 flow is typically handled on the printer.

You could make a feature request at [github](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues) to let Flow be enabled for Ultimaker 2 printers.

As for your problem: that sounds more like a dimensional accuracy problem to me. I suggest setting Horizontal Expansion to -0.15mm.